# Turn off Google Cloud Memorystore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

This might be a stupid question.
I'm just curious. I'm new to Redis and would like to experiment with it.
However, I would like to turn the instance on and off whenever I am experimenting as I want to save on costs rather than have the instance running all the time.

But I don't see a stop button like other products such as compute.
Is there a reason for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to manage a Cloud Memorystore for Redis instance as a Compute Engine instance as they are different products with different billing requirements and therefore you can't stop a Cloud Memorystore for Redis instance.

If you are only interested in learning more about Redis you can always install Redis on a Compute Engine instance (see the following [tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/blob/master/tutorials/setting-up-redis.md) for a clear path as to how to accomplish this or [this other tutorial](https://medium.com/@kuroun_seung/set-up-redis-on-gcp-virtual-machine-c84c4fac456) as to how to accomplish this task using docker) and afterwards delete the Compute Engine instance in order for charges to stop accruing.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! You are a star!
Just curious, is there any advantage of using cloud memorystore vs running my own compute engine instance with redis?

Comment: The key advantages of using Cloud Memorystore for Redis would be that it is a fully managed service (you don't have to worry about security updates, patching, automatic failover, etc.) it offers high availability and also scaling (check the rest of the features [here](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-overview#features)), so you can mainly focus on developing your application instead of managing the Redis instance.

Comment: Nonetheless, in a Compute Engine instance you'll need to take care of the all the maintenance aspects of the Redis instance, but you have the freedom of tweak the instance according to your needs, as well as sorting out the following constraints (https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/product-constraints#blocked_redis_commands) that Cloud Memorystore for Redis (notice that this being a fully managed service blocks certain Redis commands, as well as it doesn't support [Redis persistence](https://redis.io/topics/persistence)).

Comment: To understand the key differences between managed and open-source Redis. Please refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-overview#differences_between_managed_and_open_source_redis) section of the documentation.

Comment: You are amazing. Thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid incurring charges to your Google Cloud account for the resources used in this quickstart:

Go to the Memorystore for Redis page in the Cloud Console.
Memorystore for Redis
Click the instance ID of the instance you want to delete.
Click the Delete button.
In the prompt that appears, enter the instance ID.
Click Delete.

https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/quickstart-console#clean_up